# Questions about how something was made on certain website

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, asking-questions, external-links

Is it ok to point to a website and ask how this or that effect/behavior was achieved? Long time ago I asked this way and immediately got downvoted. But it's completely valid inquiry about programming-related matter, demonstrated by an example!

Comment: It is technically possible, very hard to pull off however.  You need visitors to go "hey, that's pretty interesting".  Don't be boring and anything is on topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most likely it'll be too broad and closed.

You could possibly avoid most of the downvotes by making a clear question and something along the lines of "it looks like it uses x and y which I've learnt that `[research link]()` allows it to do z efficiently".

But then you'd have done the research and may not need to ask the question at all.

Also, myself and many others will never click a random link posted on Stack Overflow which is why its important that your question is self-sufficient.

Comment: "*Most likely it'll be too broad and closed.*" I'd also add that it lacks an MCVE or is otherwise not self-contained. If that website gets a re-design tomorrow and nobody has posted an answer yet, the question becomes unanswerable. Actually, even if there is already an answer, then nobody else can add another one. The existing answer(s) might be incorrect or incomplete, for example and people won't be able to examine the site by themselves to add to or correct the information. That's in addition to reverse engineering code being much too broad of a question for SO.